# Use a database specific function in dbtng (e.g. uuid in db_insert)

Tags: 7, database

I have a table that contains a char(36) field for a uuid. It seems like I can insert data into that field with a mysql query like: `INSERT INTO mytable (uid, event_guid) VALUES (1, uuid());`. I'd like to make a query like that in *DBTNG* syntax, but I believe I will just insert the string "uuid()" into the column.

```
db_insert('mytable')
  ->fields(array('uid' => $uid, 'event_guid' => 'uuid()'))
  ->execute();
```

So...do I just use db_query? Is there some magic in dbtng to handle this?

Comment: I think you're stuck with db_query for that one, db_insert doesn't have an expression() method...unless your table has a primary key that isn't the uuid column, in which case you might be able to ever-so-slightly abuse `db_merge()` which _does_ have that method

Comment: Expressions are used from the `MergeQuery` class when the table needs to be updated, not to insert new data in the database. See [MergeQuery::execute()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21query.inc/function/MergeQuery%3A%3Aexecute/7), in particular the part after `if ($this->needsUpdate) {`.

Comment: I created an issue for this idea http://drupal.org/node/1858188

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I ultimately did:

```
db_query("INSERT INTO {mytable} (uid, event_guid) VALUES (:uid, uuid())",
array(':uid' => $uid));
```

And that works to use the mysql uuid() function in an insert.

I've created an issue to add this to Drupal 8 http://drupal.org/node/1858188

Answer (score 1):

```
            $uuid = db_query("SELECT uuid() AS uuid ")->fetchField();

            db_insert('mytable')
            ->fields(array('uid' => $uid, 'event_guid' => $uuid))
            ->execute();
```

A workaround to the problem.

Comment: An interesting idea. This would work OK for a single instance but wouldn't be great for a multi-value insert. It also is probably not super performant since you are doing two queries (one db_query, on db_insert) where my ultimate solution was one db_query("INSERT...UUID()...");

Answer (score -1):

You can use function calls in the fields array.  The following code should just work:

```
db_insert('mytable')
  ->fields(array('uid' => $uid, 'event_guid' => uuid()))
  ->execute();
```

If you wanted to insert multiple entries in a loop something like this would work:

```
$event_guid = uuid();
foreach($entries as $entry) {
  $entry['event_guid'] = $event_guid;
  db_insert('mytable')
    ->fields($entry)
    ->execute();
}
```

Comment: greggles want to use mysql's uuid function with in db_insert() not a php function :(

Comment: Knowing greggles, I would not think he is asking how to use the output from a PHP function for a query. He made that clear when he showed the equivalent SQL query he would use without the Drupal database API.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately this won't work, as kiamlaluno and Mathankumar pointed out.